# Git,Gerrit and Jenkins integration with Tuleap Server

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, tuleap

I'm newly working on Tuleap, now I'm trying to integrate git, gerrit, jenkins with tuleap server. i have installed plugins (Git,Gerrit,Jenkins) on tuleap. can any one help to me how to integrate successfully workflow on tuleap.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup separate Gerrit server and add the reference in Tuleap server. You create a project in Tuleap and add Git service, afterwards create/ init an empty repository in Tuleap and clone it in your local system. Do the work and issue a Pull request to update the repository on Tuleap. After that send it for review to Gerrit server by click commit. You can then review the code at Gerrit server and if it's accepted Push to your production system

I am still working on the Jenkins integration with Tuleap as I am also just a beginner to Tuleap.